# Is there a Seaside preference to create more human readable html, i.e. html including linebreaks?

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

The standard html output created by Seaside is all in one line, without any linebreaks.

Is there a preference to change this behavior, so that the output will be more human readable?

If not, what would be a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such preference, the reasons for this being

- HTML is sensitive to whitespace (this also depends on the styles),
- the [developer tools](http://book.seaside.st/book/fundamentals/rendering-components/fun-with-canvas) already show you pretty printed html, and
- tools like FireBug and WebKit developer tools can help you too.

Answer (score 5):

afaik, there is no such preference.

Mind that developer tools in the webbrowser (such as firebug and webkit dev tools) can show you the formatted html & have a switch to pretty-print generated javascripts.